# Using variables from another Python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, variables

I have two different .py file, is it possible to use variables of one in the other?

Sorry for my bad code but I'm still learning :)

In MainFile.py

```
from LoginFile import login

class MyApp(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_login_dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.loginCheck)
        self.Register.clicked.connect(self.registerCheck)
        self.window2 = None
        total_usernames = c.execute("SELECT USERNAME FROM register_table").fetchall()
        for data in total_usernames:
            self.comboBox.addItems(data)

    def login_check(self):
        username = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
        password = str(self.fieldpassword.text())

        login(username, password)

        # I can't read the following variables from the other file
        print(current_status)    
        print(current_username)
```

In LoginFile.py I have:

```
 def login(username, password):
     driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
     driver.get(site)
     current_username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span/span").text
     current_status = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span").text
```

Basically I would like to read "current_status" and "current_username" variables in MainFile.py imported from LoginFile.py

I already tried to import everything from the other file, with:

```
from LoginFile import *
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried to check answers from similar questions, but I wasn't able to find a solution that work in my case.

Is it possible to do it? is there a better solution to arrive to the same result?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you created another filled called `__init__.py` in the same directory?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Even if you had a function called `login` in your `main.py` file, `print(current_status)` would still fail. `login(username, password)` just calls the function and throws away any value, so at a minimum, you would need to `return` something from `login` and then assign it to something inside `login_check`.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you are trying to import are inside a function, so they are out of scope. Even if you called the function they would be destroyed when the function ends unless you return them.The other way is to put them and other logic outside the function and then upon import the logic will be executed and variables assigned, then you would have access to their values. All this is under the assumption that you did not received any errors when the interpreter hit the line where you import.

Comment: Concider acccepting the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

`from LoginFile import *` gives you access to all the functions written in the LoginFile class/module, not its variables. The common workaround way to access the variables in that class is to simply have another function like getVariable() that just returns the variable of interest. Then in the MainFile call that function by LoginFile.getVariable().

Answer (score 0):

define your directory as python directory/ package your directory strurcture look like

```
/directory 
    __init__.py
    main.py
    LoginFile.py
```